# How can I implement new JQuery to my HTML code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At this time I'm using a JQuery that make a preloading for my images array.
Before I see the images(slideshow) i see a screen of the JQuery effect that load the images then it's fading and I see the slideshow.

What I want to do is to use another JQuery but this time without a screen that will preload the images but to make this:

1. To load the first image to show/display the first image in the slideshow but without buttons yet.
2. To show/dsiplay on this first image the jquery that is a spinner pre loader that should load thei mages with percentages inside and when it finish the loading of all the rest of images then start the slideshow.

This is my html code now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"
/>

<link
    type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="Screen.css"
    media="screen,projection,tv"
/>
<style>
#preloader { width: 100%; height: 900px; background:#000; position:fixed; left:0; top:0; text-align: center; z-index:9999999999;}
#loadingbar { width: 245px; height: 245px; text-align: center; color: #fff; background: url(../img/preload_bg.gif) no-repeat 0 245px; margin-left: 38%; margin-top: 11%;}
#loadingtext { 

padding: 10px 0 0; 

font-size:18px;


}
</style>

<title>
    Slidehow Demo -  - Site Title
</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/preloader.html" type="text/css" />

</head><body>

    <div id="preloader">
  <div id="loadingbar"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-IdPZAIYB_38/UAsThCuCjcI/AAAAAAAABK0/wzErRGy13NU/s1600/loading.gif" width="345" height="245" alt="Preload Logo" /></div>
                    <div id="loadingtext"  style="color:#FFF;" ></div>
</div>
    <div id="slideShow">



    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar002407.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar002409.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007339.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar005712.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007337.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000009.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000007.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar005720.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007338.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar003137.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar003136.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000005.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar005721.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar002203.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar002202.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000010.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar003138.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000006.Gif" alt="slide" />            



    <!-- #slideShow --></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="SlideShow.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="script/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

    var imgList = [];

    $.extend({

        preload: function(imgArr, option) {

            var setting = $.extend({

                init: function(loaded, total) {},

                loaded: function(img, loaded, total) {},

                loaded_all: function(loaded, total) {}

            }, option);

            var total = imgArr.length;

            var loaded = 0;



            setting.init(0, total);

            for(var i in imgArr) {

                imgList.push($("<img />")

                    .attr("src", imgArr[i])

                    .load(function() {

                        loaded++;

                        setting.loaded(this, loaded, total);

                        if(loaded == total) {

                            setting.loaded_all(loaded, total);

                        }

                    })

                );

            }



        }

    });

})(jQuery);





$(function() {
    $.preload([
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar002407.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar002409.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007339.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar005712.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007337.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000009.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000007.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar005720.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007338.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar003137.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar003136.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000005.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar005721.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar002203.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar002202.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000010.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar003138.Gif",
        "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar000006.Gif",





        ], {

        init: function(loaded, total) {

            $(".wrapper").hide();

            $("#loadingtext").html("L o a d i n g ... p l e a s e   w a i t");

        },

        loaded: function(img, loaded, total) {

            var loader = 245-((loaded/total)*245);

            var prozent = Math.round(loaded/total*100);

            $("#loadingtext").html("L o a d i n g : "+prozent+"%");

            //$("#loadingtext").html("Lade jede Menge Inhalte: "+loaded+"/"+total);

            $("#loadingbar").css({"background-position" : "0px "+loader+"px"});

        },

        loaded_all: function(loaded, total) {
            $("#loadingtext").html("L o a d e d");
            $("#preloader").delay(500).fadeOut();
            $(".wrapper").delay(1000).fadeIn("slow");
        }

    });



});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I have two other files one with javascript and one with styling(css).
The files names are: SlideShow.js and Screen.css

This is my website as it is now with the jquery:

[Website](http://newsxpressmedia.com/SlideShow.php)

The problem is how to implement the new JQuery I want to use in this case:

bitbucket.org/Better2Web/jquery.percentageloader

Comment: This is a link of the jquery i want and trying to use now: https://bitbucket.org/Better2Web/jquery.percentageloader and a link for the jquery demo: http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/

Comment: are you asking on how to include a second script?

Comment: Andi yes but instead the one exist already. Not two jquery scripts but to replace the one is in now in the html code. And make it work as i wrote in 1. and 2. first load/display the first image to the slideshow show the first image but dont start the slideshow yet and dont show the buttons. Load with the jquery the rest of the images when they all loaded then start the slideshow and show the buttons. And again to replace the existing jquery script with this one and not to make the preview screen but as i wrote in 1 and 2. Thank you Andi.

Comment: The new jquery i want to use with the preloading is suupose to be to show/display on the first loaded image in the center of it load all the rest of images then show the buttons and start the slideshow.